# MobX + React Router Private Route Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx

Trying to set up a private route component which gets updated whenever a user's `authToken` becomes invalid.

Here is the private route:

```
    const PrivateRoute = observer(({component: Component, ...rest}: { component: any, path: any }) => {

    return (<Route {...rest} render={(props: any) => (
        authCredentialsStore.credToken
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to='/login'/>
    )}/>);
});
```

The `authCredentialsStore` is provided via import.

This is the store:

```
 class AuthCredentialsStore {

    @observable _authCredentials: AuthCredentials;
    @observable credToken = this._authCredentials ? this._authCredentials.authToken : null;

    set authCredentials(creds: AuthCredentials) {
        this._authCredentials = creds;;
    }

    get authCredentials() {
        return this._authCredentials;
    }

    removeCredentials() {
        this._authCredentials = null;
    }
}

export const authCredentialsStore = new AuthCredentials();
```

Then in the child component, I make a fetch on `componentDidMount` and if the fetch fails, I want to reset the store and redirect the user to the login page:

```
 class ChildComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {

    fetchItems(): void {
        const authToken = authCredentialsStore.credToken;
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `${authToken}`
            }
        };
        fetch('some_url', options)
            .then(res => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    authCredentialsStore.removeCredentials();
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(/*do something with results*/))
            .catch(/*do error handling*/);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchItems();
    }

    render() {...}
}
```

I expect the authToken to be reset and automatically trigger `setState` on the private route, which will cause it to rerender, and redirect to the login page, but that doesn't happen on first go. It seems like while the `authToken` is being cleared in the store, the change is not detected in the PrivateRoute component.

Comment: try assigning the value of `authCredentialsStore.credToken` to a local variable outside of the `Route`'s `render` method and in it just check it. i think now mobx is not observing it because it's in a different function scope.